# Getting data from object literal

Tags: javascript, object, object-literal

I have an object literal where I can set a persons name. In another .js-file I have an object where I instantiates the Person-object, and with the function "getName" i want to assign a persons name to a variable.

However, when I try to do that I don't get the persons name. Instead I get the whole function. Why is it this way?

```
function Person(name){

    this.getName = function(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

---

```
init: function(){
    var person = new Person("thomas");
    var name = person.getName;
    alert(name) // <- the function instead of the name
```

---

Comment: Try `var name = person.getName();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code from:

```
var name = person.getName;
```

To:

```
var name = person.getName();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to call `person.getName();` to execute the function.